# i am entering values and getting total in total field.but when i am changing values in cellfiels i am not getting total changed dynamically

Tags: javascript

// i am entering values and getting total in total field.but when i am            changing values in cellfiels i am not getting total changed dynamically.
      how to get it total cahnged in total field when values are changed in cell.?? Plz help

if i am entering a:10;b:20;c:30 then total field displays 60, but when i am changing values total is not changed,it still remains same i.e. 60

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Dynamic Form</title>
 <script>
 //function creation named changeit
 function ChangeIt() 
 {
 var str =document.getElementById("UserInput").value;
 var res = str.split(';');
 var i;
 var sum=0;
 var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
 {
 var row = table.insertRow(0);
 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 cell1.innerHTML = res[i].split(':')[0];
 var t5=document.createElement("input");
 t5.id="txt"+res[i].split(':')[0];
 t5.value=res[i].split(':')[1];
 cell2.appendChild(t5);
 alert(res[i].split(':')[0]);
 var sum1;
 sum1=res[i].split(':')[1];
 sum=parseInt(sum)+parseInt(sum1);
 }
 //addition function to get total
 function getsum() 
 {
 var sum2;
 sum2=res[i].split(':')[1];
 sum=parseInt(sum)+parseInt(sum1);
  }
 alert(sum);
 document.getElementById("UserInput1").value=sum;
 document.getElementById("UserInput1").value=getsum();
 }
 </script>
           <body>
           <input type="label" name=t1 id="UserInput">  <input type="button"                     value="click" onClick="ChangeIt()"><br><br>
            Total  <input type="label" name=t2 id="UserInput1" disabled>
           <table id="myTable">
         <div id="my_div"></div>
          </body>
      </head>
      </html>
```

Comment: set values on change event ..

Comment: the values are dynamic not static.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5052011/rohit-kumar

Comment: what's wrong in this , bind change event and calculate all the time..

Comment: can you do this plz in coding form..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5052011/rohit-kumar

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
var t5=document.createElement("input");
     t5.id="txt"+res[i].split(':')[0];
     t5.value=res[i].split(':')[1];
    t5.onChange="getsum()";
```

Comment: thanks but not working brother..http://stackoverflow.com/users/5052011/rohit-kumar